# Transmit large stream in ASP.Net without caching

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, caching, streaming

I have large amount of data from a business system which the user needs to be able to export into a CSV format for reports etc via an ASP.Net website.  I have written an efficient technique to get the response and write it through a buffered stream however I'm having some trouble with ASP.Net caching the result.

The file can be very large (500MB +) and it seems that the ASP.Net response stream is being cached locally, even if I flush the stream out to the client.  I don't want to lose 2 GB of memory on the server every time an export is run.

I have a method which I want to pass a stream (or stream writer) to which my algorithm will then write into.  Is there any special setting I need to make to prevent ASP.net from caching?  I've read some info about using HTTP Handlers and the like, but I'm not an expert in ASP.net so would greatly appreciate some info :).

Comment: have you tried 
Response.Expires = 0 
Response.CacheControl = "no-cache"

Comment: The caching is happening in IIS, so as I understand it this command would only affect the communication path between the server and client.